# Route of Angular 15, how to show raw *.json file into browser

Tags: angular, routes

A want to show raw JSON file in my Angular 15 frontend similar to ordinary Html logic

```
<a href="../api/XXXXX/YYYYY.json" target="_blank">JSON</a>
```

but I have app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   ...]
```

and this module forbid to do this simple operation.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/aes/wrongParameters.json'
```

In this relative path "api/XXXXX/YYYYY.json" I have a lot of JSON files and I need to allow show any of it.
How its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to put the json files in your asset folder then do

```
 <a href="/assets/myjson.json" target="_blank">JSON</a>
```